# Create a symbolic orthonormal matrix in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to create a 3 by 3 real orthonormal symbolic matrix in Mathematica.
How can I do so?

Comment: What kind of matrix? Mathematica has built in functions for rotation and reflection matrices, both are orthonormal.

Comment: I want to build a symbolic matrix, such that the matrix will always be treated as an orthonormal matrix, in successive computations. The command RotationMatrix in mathematica DOES NOT do this.

Comment: There is a related question on the scientific computing stackexchange http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/74/symbolic-software-packages-for-matrix-expressions

Answer (score 11):

Not that I recommend this, but...

```
m = Array[a, {3, 3}];
{q, r} = QRDecomposition[m];
q2 = Simplify[q /. Conjugate -> Identity]
```

So q2 is a symbolic orthogonal matrix (assuming we work over reals).

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your answer. Do you see any way to "directly" impose the six conditions of orthonormality and the condition of det=1, without involving QRDecomposition? Thanks. Marcello

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want  some `SO(3)` group parametrization in Mathematica I think. You will only have 3 independent symbols (variables), since you have 6 constraints from mutual orthogonality of vectors and the norms equal to 1. One way is to construct independent rotations around the 3 axes, and multiply those matrices. Here is the (perhaps too complex) code to do that:

```
makeOrthogonalMatrix[p_Symbol, q_Symbol, t_Symbol] :=
  Module[{permute, matrixGeneratingFunctions},
    permute =  Function[perm, Permute[Transpose[Permute[#, perm]], perm] &];
    matrixGeneratingFunctions = 
       Function /@ FoldList[
            permute[#2][#1] &,
            {{Cos[#], 0, Sin[#]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[#], 0, Cos[#]}},
            {{2, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 1}}];
    #1.#2.#3 & @@  MapThread[Compose, {matrixGeneratingFunctions, {p, q, t}}]];
```

Here is how this works:

```
In[62]:= makeOrthogonalMatrix[x,y,z]
Out[62]= 
{{Cos[x] Cos[z]+Sin[x] Sin[y] Sin[z],Cos[z] Sin[x] Sin[y]-Cos[x] Sin[z],Cos[y] Sin[x]},
 {Cos[y] Sin[z],Cos[y] Cos[z],-Sin[y]},
 {-Cos[z] Sin[x]+Cos[x] Sin[y] Sin[z],Cos[x] Cos[z] Sin[y]+Sin[x] Sin[z],Cos[x] Cos[y]}}
```

You can check that the matrix is orthonormal, by using `Simplify` over the various column (or row) dot products.

Comment: Leonid, Thanks for your answer. I actually want to define a generic symbolic SO(3) matrix, without starting from the Euler angles as you do. Basically I want to set a generic matrix (e.g. using mat = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]) and impose that the elements of this matrix will be treated always as satisfying the orthonormality conditions and the determinant = 1 condition, without the need of specifying this later on. Marcello

Comment: @user1087909 Then, Daniel's answer should be the way to go.

Comment: Strangely enough, in responding to the comment/question under mine, I was going to say that Leonid's was the appropriate way.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed amusing. I actually looked at my code again and realized that instead of the complicated stuff with `FoldList` etc, I should have just listed all 3 matrices explicitly - my code is very confusing for no good reason. Will change to this version soon.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a "direct" way to impose special orthogonality.
See below.

```
(*DEFINITION OF ORTHOGONALITY AND SELF ADJUNCTNESS CONDITIONS:*) 
MinorMatrix[m_List?MatrixQ] := Map[Reverse, Minors[m], {0, 1}] 
CofactorMatrix[m_List?MatrixQ] := MapIndexed[#1 (-1)^(Plus @@ #2) &, MinorMatrix[m], {2}] 
UpperTriangle[ m_List?MatrixQ] := {m[[1, 1 ;; 3]], {0, m[[2,   2]], m[[2, 3]]}, {0, 0, m[[3, 3]]}}; 
FlatUpperTriangle[m_List?MatrixQ] := Flatten[{m[[1, 1 ;; 3]], m[[2, 2 ;; 3]], m[[3, 3]]}];
Orthogonalityconditions[m_List?MatrixQ] := Thread[FlatUpperTriangle[m.Transpose[m]] == FlatUpperTriangle[IdentityMatrix[3]]]; 
Selfadjunctconditions[m_List?MatrixQ] := Thread[FlatUpperTriangle[CofactorMatrix[m]] == FlatUpperTriangle[Transpose[m]]]; 
SO3conditions[m_List?MatrixQ] := Flatten[{Selfadjunctconditions[m], Orthogonalityconditions[m]}]; 

(*Building of an SO(3) matrix*) 
mat = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]; 
$Assumptions = SO3conditions[mat]
```

Then

```
Simplify[Det[mat]]
```

gives 1;...and

```
MatrixForm[Simplify[mat.Transpose[mat]]
```

gives the identity matrix;
...finally

```
MatrixForm[Simplify[CofactorMatrix[mat] - Transpose[mat]]]
```

gives a Zero matrix.

========================================================================

This is what I was looking for when I asked my question!
However, let me know your thought on this method.

Marcellus

Answer (score 3):

Marcellus, you have to use some parametrization of SO(3), since your general matrix has to reflect the [**RP**<sup>3</sup> topology of the group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Low_dimensional). No single parametrization will cover the whole group without either multivaluedness or singular points. Wikipedia has a nice page about the various [charts on SO(3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charts_on_SO%283%29).

Maybe one of the conceptually simplest is the exponential map from the Lie algebra so(3).
Define an antisymmetric, real `A` (which spans so(3))

```
A = {{0, a, -c},
     {-a, 0, b},
     {c, -b, 0}};
```

Then `MatrixExp[A]` is an element of `SO(3)`. 
We can check that this is so, using

```
Transpose[MatrixExp[A]].MatrixExp[A] == IdentityMatrix[3] // Simplify
```

If we write `t^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2`, we can simplify the matrix exponential down to

```
{{   b^2 + (a^2 + c^2) Cos[t]  , b c (1 - Cos[t]) + a t Sin[t], a b (1 - Cos[t]) - c t Sin[t]}, 
 {b c (1 - Cos[t]) - a t Sin[t],    c^2 + (a^2 + b^2) Cos[t]  , a c (1 - Cos[t]) + b t Sin[t]}, 
 {a b (1 - Cos[t]) + c t Sin[t], a c (1 - Cos[t]) - b t Sin[t],    a^2 + (b^2 + c^2) Cos[t]}} / t^2
```

Note that this is basically the same parametrization as [RotationMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationMatrix.html) gives.
Compare with the output from

```
RotationMatrix[s, {b, c, a}] // ComplexExpand // Simplify[#, Trig -> False] &;
% /. a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -> 1
```

Comment: Excellent answer. However, I prefer to define a matrix satisfying the SO(3) conditions more directly...see my answer above, and let me know what you think. Marcellus

Answer (score 2):

Although I really like the idea of Marcellus' answer to his own question, it's not completely correct. Unfortunately, the conditions he arrives at also result in

```
Simplify[Transpose[mat] - mat]
```

evaluating to a zero matrix! This is clearly not right. Here's an approach that's both correct and more direct:

```
OrthogonalityConditions[m_List?MatrixQ] := Thread[Flatten[m.Transpose[m]] == Flatten[IdentityMatrix[3]]];
SO3Conditions[m_List?MatrixQ] := Flatten[{OrthogonalityConditions[m], Det[m] == 1}];
```

i.e. multiplying a rotation matrix by its transpose results in the identity matrix, and the determinant of a rotation matrix is 1.